# Transliteration failed to recognize Yu as a combination, instead it transliterates it by y and u itself

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a transliteration class. However, the second test `LatinToCyrillicTextShouldEqualTheirEqual` fails because it doesn't recognize Yu as a combination. Instead it transliterates Y and u alone. How do I fix it?

```cs
public sealed class Transliteration
{
    private const string CyrillicLowercase = "а б в г д е ж з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ц ч ш щ ъ ь ю я";
    private const string CyrillicUppercase = "А Б В Г Д Е Ж З И Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ Ь Ю Я";
    private const string LatinLowercase = "a b v g d e zh z i y k l m n o p r s t u f h ts ch sh sht a y yu ya";
    private const string LatinUppercase = "A B V G D E Zh Z I Y K L M N O P R S T U F H Ts Ch Sh Sht A Y Yu Ya";
    
    private readonly Dictionary<string,string> _dict;

    private Transliteration()
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    private Transliteration(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(dict);
        
        _dict = dict;
    }
    
    public static Transliteration Create()
    {
        var lowercaseDict = CyrillicLowercase.Split(' ')
            .Zip(LatinLowercase.Split(' '), (k, v) => new { k, v })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);

        var uppercaseDict = CyrillicUppercase.Split(' ')
            .Zip(LatinUppercase.Split(' '), (k, v) => new { k, v })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);

        var both = lowercaseDict.Concat(uppercaseDict)
            .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, g => g.First());

        return new Transliteration(both);
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Transliterates cyrillic text to latin.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text to be transliterated.</param>
    /// <returns>The transliterated text.</returns>
    public string CyrillicToLatin(string text)
    {
        return _dict.Aggregate(text, (current, pair) => current.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value));
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Transliterates latin text to cyrillic.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text to be transliterated.</param>
    /// <returns>The transliterated text.</returns>
    public string LatinToCyrillic(string text)
    {
        return _dict.Aggregate(text, (current, pair) => current.Replace(pair.Value, pair.Key));
    }
}
```

```cs
public class TransliterationTests
{
    private readonly Transliteration _transliteration;
    
    public TransliterationTests()
    {
        _transliteration = Transliteration.Create();
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void CyrillicToLatinTextShouldEqualTheirEqual()
    {
        // Arrange

        
        // Act
        var actual = _transliteration.CyrillicToLatin("Юлия Колева Хаджииванова");

        // Assert
        actual.Should().Be("Yuliya Koleva Hadzhiivanova");
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void LatinToCyrillicTextShouldEqualTheirEqual()
    {
        // Arrange

        
        // Act
        var actual = _transliteration.LatinToCyrillic("Yuliya Koleva Hadzhiivanova");

        // Assert
        actual.Should().Be("Юлия Колева Хаджииванова");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Aggregate(text, ...` operates on character level. To recognize the multi-character sequences, you have to look at the next characters in certain cases.

Comment: @KlausGütter yes that's right. It has to be changed

Comment: @KlausGütter, the following worked `public string LatinToCyrillic(string text)
    {
        return _dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Length).Aggregate(text, (current, pair) => current.Replace(pair.Value, pair.Key));
    }`

Comment: @KlausGütter, first checking the highest length and then anything else.

Comment: You can post this as answer to your own question.